# R packages which allow ensemble models for multi-class outcomes?

Tags: r

I'm searching for R packages which can build ensemble predictive models for multi-class outcomes.

So far I've ruled out the `SuperLearner` and `caretEnsemble` packages. It appears the `h2o` package supports multi-class ensemble predictive models, unfortunately my company's firewall prevents us installing the package.

Are there any others I've missed? Thanks

Comment: The `sl3` package can do this, but it is not on CRAN. You can find it on GitHub [here](https://tlverse.org/sl3/).

Comment: but `sl3` says outcome type should be continuous. Does it support multi-class classification where the outcome is a factor with multiple classes/levels e.g., strings?